# handling multiple cameras with OpenCV and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, video-capture

I'm trying to set up a neural network to work on multiple cameras simultaneously (or almost at least..). First of all i'm trying to get to stream 2 cameras at once with OpenCV and the python threading module.

I've come up with this code:

```
import cv2
import threading
import queue

def multistream(stream, q):
    ret, frame = stream.read()
    q.put(frame)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   camlink1 = "rtsp://......link1"
   camlink2 = "rtsp://......link2"
   stream1 = cv2.VideoCapture(camlink1)
   stream2 = cv2.VideoCapture(camlink2)
   print("stream is opened")
   while True:
      q = queue.Queue()
      cam1 = threading.Thread(target=multistream, args=(stream1, q))
      cam2 = threading.Thread(target=multistream, args=(stream2, q))
      cam1.start()
      cam2.start()
      cam1.join()
      cam2.join()
      while not q.empty():
          cv2.imshow("video", q.get())
```

The problem is that cv2.imshow shows an empty window instead of the frame while, if i add to the code `print(q.get())`, it prints the mats of which the frame is made, so the frame is correctly returned from the multistream function to the main thread. What's the correct fix for this?

Comment: Huh? Why create a new queue and start a new thread for every frame? Rather start your two threads that each run a loop acquiring frames and sending them to your `main`.

Comment: yeah, i figured it out right after and it worked as you said

Comment: @simonEE can you please tell me the changes you made in your code?